# Grape returning 404's on successful requests under Passenger

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, ruby-grape

I've built a small Rack service that uses Grape for an API and Sinatra for serving static assets. I'm using `Rack::Cascade` to run both the grape service and sinatra and docker for deploying.

I've been trying to implement Passenger in standalone mode for SSL but I've been running into some issues. All requests to sinatra are working as expected but my requests to the grape endpoint are not. All requests to my grape endpoints return `404`'s in the logs but appear to be successful otherwise:

```
"GET /api/v1/voice/test HTTP/1.1" 404
```

returns `{"test":"123"}` and a `200` from curl